# How do I know when a filter coffee machine is finished by using any sensor?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, arduino-nano, nodemcu

I have a filter coffee machine that looks like [this one](https://www.electrolux.com.tr/kitchen/small-kitchen-appliances/coffee-makers/coffee-maker/ekf5300/) and I would like to send a message to the machine users by using any development board (like Arduino or NodeMcu) when the machine is finished.

I haven't found a way to detect when the machine is finished. (I also don't want to do any physical change on the machine, like adding any cable or opening in the machine. I can use any sensor or so on.)

How can I do that? Any advice?

Comment: Maybe a capacitive level sensor at the side of the pot? That might work. Or maybe a reflective light sensor on the pot (LED plus phototransistor, which senses the change in reflected light, when the coffee reaches a specific level)

Comment: measure the power consumption

Comment: Ultrasonic: measure the height of the water. Will be hard to fix inside the machine and probably hard to get a water proof version.

Comment: Easiest and cheapest: measure the maximum time it takes to make coffee and then use a timer. The coffee will be kept warm anyways, so just come back after x minutes.

Comment: weight sensor under the cup? are there some LEDs to indicate status?

Comment: (Just a note...) This was done many, many years ago: [Trojan Room coffee pot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_Room_coffee_pot) -- However, a camera might be a bit exaggerated.

Comment: The normal method is by temperature. When you heat the water you can never get above 100C as the water boiling takes the extra energy away in the phase change to steam. But once all the water has been removed from the heating tank the heater can get higher that 100C. So when that happens the heater shuts off as it's got no more water to heat up.  Basic physics.  So monitor the temperature of the heater then allow a certain amount of extra time for the last bit to filter (determined by experimentation).

Answer (score 1):

Just two ideas, both non-invasive:

The machine moves water from the reservoir at the back to the coffeepot at the front of the machine, so its weight distribution will change while making coffee.

If you put a thin pressure pad (like [this one](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Round_Force_Sensor_FSR402/), or something similar) under the whole machine at the back you should see the pressure at that point become smaller while coffee is being made.

If the effect isn't pronounced enough, you could make the whole machine tilt forward while making coffee by putting a narrow and thin strip of plastic under its centre from left to right so it can swivel forward and back just a little depending on the location of the bulk of the water.

If the pressure on the pressure pad at the back stops dropping, the coffee is ready. You can also detect when the coffee can is empty again this way, or maybe even how many cups of coffee are still available in the coffee can.

Or maybe you could detect with a contact microphone when the machine goes silent, assuming it makes sufficient noise when making coffee. Mine does.

Comment: I'd use two load cells instead of those pressure pads. But other than that, this is a nice solution.

Comment: Added benefit it that it can notify you when there is less that a cup of coffee left in the pot, and thuse requiring a refill.

Comment: Even easier would be to only measure the entire weight of the machine. A sudden increase of weight, indicates it's just filled up. Start a timer for, say, 2 minutes, plus 1 minute for every 100ml (i.e. 100gr). You'd have to do some test runs to measure the amount of time needed for different amounts of water. (You could even make it help you measuring out the right amount of ground coffee.)

Answer (score 0):

If the machine has a Brewing- or a Done Brewing LED, a light sensor can detect this without no changes or connections to the machine. This would also have the advantage of working for a short or full pot.